# android unix timestamp in sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, date, timestamp

I have a problem with unix timestamps in sqlite.

I want to store the result of System.currentTimeMillis() in sqllite (integer). But when i read the stored value from the db, i always get a negativ value like -203027418, and not the value, i stored, like 1494445606119

Here is the scheme of my db:

```
 // Database creation sql statement
private static final String CREATE_ROUTE = "create table "
        + TABLE_ROUTE + "("
        + ROUTE_COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + ROUTE_COLUMN_DATE + " integer);";

private static final String CREATE_LOCATION = " create table "
        + TABLE_LOCATION + "("
        + LOCATION_COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + LOCATION_COLUMN_ROUTEID + " integer, "
        + LOCATION_COLUMN_LAT + " real, "
        + LOCATION_COLUMN_LONG + " real, "
        + LOCATION_COLUMN_DATE + " integer, "
        + " FOREIGN KEY(" + LOCATION_COLUMN_ROUTEID + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_ROUTE + "(" + ROUTE_COLUMN_ID + "));";`
```

Screenshots from debugging:

At storing, the value seems fine:
[value in object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxaRK.png)

but, when i read from db, i only get such values:
[value after reading from DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZxJ1.png)

Anyone know, whats happening here?

Comment: You might find it much easier and more useful to store date-time values in SQLite as text, using the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats such as `2017-01-23T12:34:56.789Z`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because the SQLite expects a timestamp in *seconds*, but not *milliseconds*. When you try to store the timestamp in milliseconds, overflow happens and the SQLite saves negative integer instead of timestsamp.

Comment: i also tried `locationObject.setDate(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);` , but i got the same results.

Comment: try `locationObject.setDate((int) (System.currentTimeMillis()/1000));`

Comment: I don't believe that the issue is that SQLite expects a timestamp in seconds. I believe the issue is to do with a timestamp being a **long** and that it is either being stored or retrieved as an **int**, outside of SQLIte. I have no problems storing timestamps.

Comment: ok, the int cast, as suggested by @JohnSmith seems to do the trick, thank you very much!

Comment: @MikeT: yes, outside of sqlite i handle it as a long, but AFAIK, sqlite doesn't have an explicit type for long. May i ask how you handle something like this?

Comment: SQLite's INT is capable of holding a long. Using INT is fine for a long. *INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.* from https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Answer (score 0):

An example of storing (updating) a timestamp (as requested by Julian).

```
        long newdate = adjustcal.getTimeInMillis();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_ACTON_COL,newdate);
        String whereclause = DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_ID_COL_FULL + " = ?";
        String whereargs[] = new String[] { Long.toString(ruleid)};
        updatecount = db.update(DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_TABLE,cv,whereclause,whereargs);
```

This gets the newly adjusted timestamp from adjustcal (Calendar object) as a long (with millsecs) and then updates the ACTON column for the respective RULE.

Here's an example of extracting the ACTON column (*as used in a CursorAdapter for a ListView*)

```
nextdate.setText(sdf.format(csr.getLong(rules_ruleacton_offset)));
```

`sdf` is a SimpleDateFormat. Note the use of the `getLong()` method, an SQLite Cursor method.

This is the code I use for inserting a Rule (ACTON is the 6th paramter, also note that the productid and aisleid are also longs (references to other _id columns of related tables).

```
    void insertRule(long productid,
                    long aisleid,
                    String rulename,
                    int numbertoget,
                    boolean promptflag,
                    long actondate,
                    int period,
                    int multiplier) {

        long addedid;
        lastruleaddok = false;

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_PRODUCTREF_COL,productid);
        cv.put(DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_AISLEREF_COL,aisleid);
        cv.put(DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_NAME_COL,rulename);
        cv.put(DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_USES_COL,numbertoget);
        cv.put(DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_PROMPT_COL,promptflag);
        cv.put(DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_ACTON_COL,actondate);
        cv.put(DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_PERIOD_COL,period);
        cv.put(DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_MULTIPLIER_COL,multiplier);
        addedid = db.insert(DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_TABLE,
                null,
                cv);
        if (addedid >= 0) {
            lastruleadded = addedid;
            lastruleaddok = true;
        }
    }
```

Here's a screenshot of the Rules table (note the column name is actually ruleacton rather than ACTON as used above). This shows the timestamps (note I purposefully set millisecs and seconds to 0 as in this case I'm only interested in the date).

[image]

Comment: I appreciate this very much! Thank you for your effort!